# How do I load date-based, user specific information into separate date columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

The title may be misleading, but I didn't know how else to ask this question.

I have a sql table in the following format with some example entries added

```
User  ||  Color  ||  Date
----------------------------
John  || R       || 08/15 
John  || G       || 08/16 
John  || Y       || 08/17 
Joey  || R       || 08/15 
Joey  || G       || 08/17
```

I want to know how to create a query or procedure that produces the following result

```
User || 08/15  ||  08/16  ||  08/17
------------------------------------
John || R      || G       || Y
Joe  || R      || NULL    || G
```

I have tried the below code and it got me close (I think) but I couldn't figure out how to get the color value to populate the day field

```
DECLARE @6DaysAgo NVARCHAR(5) = LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-6,GETDATE()) AS DATE), 101),5)
DECLARE @5DaysAgo NVARCHAR(5) = LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-5,GETDATE()) AS DATE), 101),5)
DECLARE @4DaysAgo NVARCHAR(5) = LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-4,GETDATE()) AS DATE), 101),5)
DECLARE @3DaysAgo NVARCHAR(5) = LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-3,GETDATE()) AS DATE), 101),5)
DECLARE @2DaysAgo NVARCHAR(5) = LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-2,GETDATE()) AS DATE), 101),5)
DECLARE @1DayAgo NVARCHAR(5) = LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()) AS DATE), 101),5)
DECLARE @Today NVARCHAR(5) = LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), 101),5)

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
SELECT t2.Username, 
    Color,
    CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS [' + @7DaysAgo + '],
    CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-6,GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS [' + @6DaysAgo + '],
    CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-5,GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS [' + @5DaysAgo + '],
    CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-4,GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS [' + @4DaysAgo + '],
    CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-3,GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS [' + @3DaysAgo + '],
    CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-2,GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS [' + @2DaysAgo + '],
    CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS [' + @1DayAgo + '],
    CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS [' + @Today + '],
    CAST(DateEntered AS DATE) AS [Date] 
FROM TABLE t 
    INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t1.UserID = t2.UserID 
WHERE CAST(DateEntered AS DATE) > DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Sorry if this is ambiguous, this is my first post on stack overflow. If this has been asked/solved before please direct me to the answering post

EDIT: Sample of output from above query
[QueryResults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yc51.png)

Comment: Do you need the output to actually be a table or is this getting pushed to an array (or other data object) in your program?

Comment: FYI, syntax like `'...[' + @1DayAgo + ']..'` is **not** injection safe. The best way to ensure a dynamic object is injection safe is by using `QUOTENAME`.

Comment: Also, I would expect the above the fail. A value like `'08/15'` cannot be implicitly (or explicitly) cast to a `date`. Is your sample data representative?

Comment: @AltimusPrime The data will be loaded into a gridview for an ASP.NET web application, so the result does not need to be a table in itself, just a query or procedure that produces these results

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for the catch! I figured this wasn't the best/safest way to approach this, but I was running out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are after here appears to be a dynamic pivot, due to having the dynamic names for the columns. Note you will need to amend this to fit the real query you have. If your source query is parametrised, you will also need to parametrise your call to `sys.sp_executesql` (**not** inject the values):

```sql
/*
User  ||  Color  ||  Date
----------------------------
John  || R       || 08/15 
John  || G       || 08/16 
John  || Y       || 08/17 
Joey  || R       || 08/15 
Joey  || G       || 08/17
*/
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable ([User] nvarchar(50), --USER is a reserved keyword, I suggest using different name
                            Colour char(1),
                            [Date] date);
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable ([User],Colour,[Date])
VALUES ('John','R','20200815'), --Assumed 2020 as MM/dd is not a valid date 
       ('John','G','20200816'), --Assumed 2020 as MM/dd is not a valid date 
       ('John','Y','20200817'), --Assumed 2020 as MM/dd is not a valid date 
       ('Joey','R','20200815'), --Assumed 2020 as MM/dd is not a valid date 
       ('Joey','G','20200817'); --Assumed 2020 as MM/dd is not a valid date
GO

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT [User],' + @CRLF +
           N'       MAX(CASE [Date] WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar(8),DATEADD(DAY, -6, GETDATE()),112),'''') + N' THEN Colour END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar(10),DATEADD(DAY, -6, GETDATE()),101)) + N',' + @CRLF +
           N'       MAX(CASE [Date] WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar(8),DATEADD(DAY, -5, GETDATE()),112),'''') + N' THEN Colour END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar(10),DATEADD(DAY, -5, GETDATE()),101)) + N',' + @CRLF +
           N'       MAX(CASE [Date] WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar(8),DATEADD(DAY, -4, GETDATE()),112),'''') + N' THEN Colour END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar(10),DATEADD(DAY, -4, GETDATE()),101)) + N',' + @CRLF +
           N'       MAX(CASE [Date] WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar(8),DATEADD(DAY, -3, GETDATE()),112),'''') + N' THEN Colour END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar(10),DATEADD(DAY, -3, GETDATE()),101)) + N',' + @CRLF +
           N'       MAX(CASE [Date] WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar(8),DATEADD(DAY, -2, GETDATE()),112),'''') + N' THEN Colour END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar(10),DATEADD(DAY, -2, GETDATE()),101)) + N',' + @CRLF +
           N'       MAX(CASE [Date] WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar(8),DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()),112),'''') + N' THEN Colour END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar(10),DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()),101)) + N',' + @CRLF +
           N'       MAX(CASE [Date] WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar(8),GETDATE(),112),'''') + N' THEN Colour END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar(10),GETDATE(),101)) + @CRLF +
           N'FROM dbo.YourTable' + @CRLF +
           N'GROUP BY [User];';
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was looking for!! No hard-coded data, tried with mutliple different sets of entries, everything looks perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to *pivot*.

I think there's a pivoting function in SQL Server, but I prefer to write SQL that works, ideally, the same no matter what the database is - except in few, very special cases.

As SQL lives and dies with the rigidity of the columns in a table, or the columns in a result set, you can't avoid writing a SQL containing exactly the final output columns. And reducing the number of rows as you do is achieved with GROUP-ing.

Also, I renamed the columns "user" and "date" to avoid reserved words.

```
WITH
input(usr,color,dt) AS (
          SELECT 'John','R',DATE '2020-08-15'
UNION ALL SELECT 'John','G',DATE '2020-08-16'
UNION ALL SELECT 'John','Y',DATE '2020-08-17'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Joey','R',DATE '2020-08-15'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Joey','G',DATE '2020-08-17'
)
SELECT
  usr
, MAX(CASE dt  WHEN '2020-08-15' THEN color END) AS col_08_15 
, MAX(CASE dt  WHEN '2020-08-16' THEN color END) AS col_08_16
, MAX(CASE dt  WHEN '2020-08-17' THEN color END) AS col_08_17
FROM input
GROUP BY
  usr;
-- out  usr  | col_08_15 | col_08_16 | col_08_17 
-- out ------+-----------+-----------+-----------
-- out  John | R         | G         | Y
-- out  Joey | R         | (NULL)    | G
```

You can use ... `AS "02/15"`  instead of `AS col_08_15` (in double quotes) if you really want that "column name"

Comment: Both this and @LONG's answers give the same result but I will mark this as the accepted answer for the extra explanation. My last question on the topic is: How can I neatly incorporate table values for usr/color/dt instead of hard coding the data in? Will I need a separate SELECT user,color,dt FROM table WHERE dt = SOMEDATE for each entry in my table?

Answer (score 0):

You might look for `Pivot`? If so:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT 'John' as [User], 'R' as color,        '08/15' as Date 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'John' as [User], 'G' as color,        '08/16' as Date 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'John' as [User], 'Y' as color,        '08/17' as Date 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Joey' as [User], 'R' as color,        '08/15' as Date   
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Joey' as [User], 'G' as color,        '08/17' as Date 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
PIVOT( MAX(color) for [DATE] in ([08/15],[08/16],[08/17])) A
```

Comment: I will try this out and see how it goes, I have never used PIVOT in SQL so there will be a delay in selected this answer as resolved until I figure out what this query does

Comment: This answer does indeed give the correct results, but I have marked @marcothesane's answer as accepted because of a little added explanation for the next person to find. Thanks again for the quick response!